# Unable to drag if formula which contains data from another workbook

Tags: if-statement, formula, excel-indirect, drag

I have an if formula as follows =if(c3>0,(""),(workbook1! a2)) how do I drag it to copy across sequential cells a2, a3, a etc without having to manually type?

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell with the formula. Type `ctrl + c` to copy. After that, hold shift and use the arrow keys to select the cells you want to populate. Then hit `ctrl + alt + v` to paste special. After that, hit `f` for formulas, then `enter`.

Comment: Many thanks... Found also I had a silly sticking point $.... Yes I locked the end reference. All sorted now thanks again

Comment: Hey, if this worked, can you mark it as the correct answer? That way people in the future with the same question can get the same help!